# Creating a PWA for GeoGebra Applets so that they work offline without needing internet connection

Tags: applet, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb, offline-caching, geogebra

I want to build a pwa website that will host offline geogebra applets without need the user to have geogebra installed. I have already built a working local website but it needs internet for the geogebra applets to work. I want the Geogebra applets to work offline, not to require internet connection.

I have already built a locally hosted website and also converted it to an apk using cordova. The website or the app works work well when online.

I have tried creating a pwa website version and it works well. The service works are fine and I score above 80% on lighthouse but the problem is that the pwa doesn't back or store the geogebra applets so that they work when offline.

How do I achieve what I want. Below is my Service Workers Code:

```
// sw.js - Service Worker

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('app-cache').then((cache) => {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/',
                'index.html',
                'styles.css',
                'script.js',
                'manifest.json',
                'offline.html',
                '/STEAM/steamApp1.html',
                'https://www.geogebra.org/m/kkdqjbxa',
                // Add other resources here as needed
            ]);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    // Handle GeoGebra applets separately using a proxy server
    if (event.request.url.startsWith('https://www.geogebra.org/')) {
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(event.request)
                .then((fetchResponse) => {
                    // Check if the response is valid and cacheable
                    if (!fetchResponse || fetchResponse.status !== 200 || fetchResponse.type !== 'basic') {
                        return fetchResponse;
                    }

                    const responseToCache = fetchResponse.clone();

                    caches.open('app-cache').then((cache) => {
                        cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                    });

                    return fetchResponse;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Fetch error:', error);

                    // Respond with the offline page as a fallback
                    return caches.match('offline.html'); // Update with the correct path
                })
        );
    } else {
        // Handle other requests using cache
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then((response) => {
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                }

                return fetch(event.request)
                    .then((fetchResponse) => {
                        // Check if the response is valid and cacheable
                        if (!fetchResponse || fetchResponse.status !== 200 || fetchResponse.type !== 'basic') {
                            return fetchResponse;
                        }

                        const responseToCache = fetchResponse.clone();

                        caches.open('app-cache').then((cache) => {
                            cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                        });

                        return fetchResponse;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error('Fetch error:', error);

                        // Respond with the offline page as a fallback
                        return caches.match('offline.html'); // Update with the correct path
                    });
            })
        );
    }
});

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if (event.data.type === 'my-message') {
        event.waitUntil(
            // Perform asynchronous operations here
            // and then send a response back to the main thread
            self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
                // Respond to the main thread
                clients.forEach(client => {
                    client.postMessage({ type: 'my-response', data: 'response-data' });
                });
            })
        );
    }
});


// service-worker.js

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if (event.data.type === 'perform-async-operation') {
        event.waitUntil(
            performAsyncOperation(event.data.payload)
                .then(result => {
                    // Respond to the main thread with a success message
                    self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
                        clients.forEach(client => {
                            client.postMessage({ type: 'async-operation-result', success: true, data: result });
                        });
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // Respond to the main thread with an error message
                    self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
                        clients.forEach(client => {
                            client.postMessage({ type: 'async-operation-result', success: false, error: error.message });
                        });
                    });
                })
        );
    }
});

function performAsyncOperation(payload) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Simulate an async operation, e.g., fetching data from a remote server
        setTimeout(() => {
            const randomValue = Math.random();
            if (randomValue > 0.5) {
                resolve(`Async operation successful with payload: ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`);
            } else {
                reject(new Error('Async operation failed'));
            }
        }, 2000); // Simulate a delay
    });
}


JavaScript:
// script.js - Handling info button click and service worker registration
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const infoButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".info-button");

    infoButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const applet = button.closest(".applet");
            applet.classList.toggle("info-open");
        });
    });

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
            .then((registration) => {
                console.log('Service Worker registered with scope:', registration.scope);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
            });
    }
});

// Service worker fetch event handling
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then((response) => {
            if (response) {
                return response;
            }

            return fetch(event.request).then((response) => {
                if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                    return response;
                }

                const responseToCache = response.clone();

                caches.open('app-cache').then((cache) => {
                    cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                });

                return response;
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Fetch error:', error);
            // You can provide a fallback response here if needed.
        })
    );
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then((response) => {
            if (response) {
                return response;
            }

            return fetch(event.request)
                .then((response) => {
                    // Check if the response is valid and cacheable
                    if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                        return response;
                    }

                    const responseToCache = response.clone();

                    caches.open('app-cache').then((cache) => {
                        cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                    });

                    return response;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Fetch error:', error);

                    // Respond with the offline page as a fallback
                    return caches.match('offline.html'); // Update with the correct path
                });
        })
    );
});

// script.js - Handling info button click and service worker registration
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const infoButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".info-button");

    infoButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const applet = button.closest(".applet");
            applet.classList.toggle("info-open");
        });
    });

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
            .then((registration) => {
                console.log('Service Worker registered with scope:', registration.scope);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the pages you are grabbing via URLs like `https://www.geogebra.org/m/kkdqjbxa` have lots of internal `<script>` tags referring back to assets on the geogebra server. Note that you can manually create embedded GeoGebra applets (see https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Apps_Embedding) and there is an encoding called ggbBase64 that completely records any possible state of an applet. So you might get it to work offline if you can grab the ggbBase64 encodings of the applets you want, and then when offline, create applet instances initialized from them.